# How can I speed up the way OS X takes a window into full screen

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I click the green circle at the top left of my screen so my window can go into full-screen mode.

Then I have to wait while my Mac performs some unnecessary animation to show me that I'm going into full-screen mode.

Can I eliminate that animation and go into full-screen instantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a sip of your tea - it's finished ;)

afaik, you can't bypass it.

My guess is it's to mask the amount of 'effort' it takes to do the transition, smooth zoom rather than lumpy pseudo-instant transition with bits of broken screen til it's finished.

Comment: The slowness is such a momentum killer, but I think you're right. There's no way to bypass it. Thanks for explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,
System Preferences > Accessibility > Display
And turn on "Reduce motion".

Comment: Though this does change the animation, I don't think it actually reduces the animation time when resizing windows to fullscreen.